# How to get the remaining follower conversations?

Tags: achievements, diablo-iii

I've just finished Diablo III and try to get the *Listen to all <...> conversations* for the followers.

However, no matter if I talk to them while they are hired or not, some options are not available:

- (Templar) Adria's Betrayal
- (Scoundrel) A Dark Outlook
- (Enchantress) Eirena's Journey
- (Enchantress) A Lost Friend

Did I miss something? Do I need to finish a higher difficulty to get these?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### TP to town at the very beginning of Act 4 Quest 1 (Fall of the High Heavens) for "A Lost Friend", "A Dark Outlook", and "Adria's Betrayal"

[image: "A Lost Friend"]
[image: "A Dark Outlook"]
[image: "Adria's Betrayal"]

#### The Enchantress's "Eirena's Journey" is available for most of Act 2 (from the very beginning), but Act 2 Quest 2 (The Road to Alcarnus) will spawn you right next to her:

[image: "Eirena's Journey"]

Conversation availability does not change between difficulties, but some conversations are only available for brief periods (esp. with the jeweler and blacksmith). You can load these levels and get them immediately, though. For what it's worth, those A4Q1 conversations above were the most elusive of the lot.

Answer (score 4):

- (Templar) Adria's Betrayal
- (Scoundrel) A Dark Outlook
- (Enchantress) A Lost Friend

When you start act IV, take the waypoint back to Bastion's Keep and talk to the followers to get these above.

Still looking when I need to talk to Eirena to get "Eirena's Journey".
If you need to talk to one of the, the follower must no be hired at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

They have specific points when they are available. Like Templar, who requires tyrael to be in same party. out of those 4 , I only know that u need to talk to enchantress during the first quest in Act IV.

Answer (score 0):

Found them. Eirena's journey is open from start (act II). U just have to talk to her when she is not in  your party, same with dark lookout, but only in act IV. Adrial's betrayl same thing after adrial has betrayed you.

Comment: Please update your initial answer and delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished all of the conversation achievements last night, ending with Tyreals conversations right before you go to Diablo. But what I did was try to relate the conversation topic to a specific point of the story, go to normal difficulty and reload checkpoints on where I thought the conversations to be.

A bit tedious yes, but one important thing I learned was to **make sure you take the quest/talk to the main questline person first. As it usually unlocks specific conversations that most people miss.**