# How do I unlock dialogues?

Tags: diablo-iii

Whenever I complete quests or subquests, I immediately go back to town to sell items and see if one of my companions has something new to say.

However, it seems awkward that still, quite many dialogues from all companions seem to be missing. Example Screenshot:

[image: Oh, how I love Covetous Shen.]

What are the possible preconditions to unlock character dialogue? Do I have to have visited certain places (maybe dungeons?), or have done certain things, found certain lore books? Do I have to take follower's with me to certain events in order to unlock certain dialogue sequences specifically for them? What is it?

Also, do I have to meet these preconditions again when I'm starting a new game on a higher difficulty, or do dialogues stay unlocked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the remaining follower conversations?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67016/how-to-get-the-remaining-follower-conversations)

Answer (score 2):

What are the possible preconditions to unlock character dialogue?

- Character dialogues are only available during certain /windows/.
  They are both locked and unlocked by starting and ending quests.
  Some dialogues for example, are only available after you have finished one quest but before you've started the next.

  Do I have to have visited certain places (maybe dungeons?), or have done certain things, found certain lore books? Do I have to take follower's with me to certain events in order to unlock certain dialogue sequences specifically for them?
- All dialogues can be gotten even in a co-op game where followers cannot accompany you, and dialogues are separate from lore books and not dependent upon them or exploration.

  Also, do I have to meet these preconditions again when I'm starting a new game on a higher difficulty, or do dialogues stay unlocked?
- Again, the conditions which lock and unlock dialogues are identical in each difficulty. For example: The time frame where you can have the dialogue with Deckard Cain about King Leoric is the same in each difficulty.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell, they are time based, but there may be more to it.

Comment: Hey, @baronmorrath.  Please try to read the [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq).  Your answers are not adding anything new or actually answering the question, which is why they're getting downvoted.