# When can I get Adria's conversations for the Bewitched achievement?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

The achievement says to "Listen to all of Adria's conversations."

In order to not miss any, I'd like to know when Adria's conversations become available and if and when they become unavailable.

Comment: i believe answering your own questions when there are already answers is pretty pointless. Are you trying to gain points?

Comment: @RenoYeo a) where are these answers? If the question is a duplicate then that's because I didn't find the original question. b) Click on Ask a Question - It gives you the option to answer your own question. It is officially okay to answer your own question or they wouldn't put the option there. c) Reputation would be nice, but the main idea behind answering a question as you ask it is for the sake of documentation. I have the answers so I post them.

Comment: The downvoting indicates that there is a problem with the question. If this is actually the case, could someone please leave a comment on how it can be improved?

Comment: I think it's because you opted to clutter the site with 5 questions for each potential conversee rather than one comprehensive Q and A.

Comment: Link to all conversation achievements http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72159/how-to-collect-all-diablo-3-conversation-achievements

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the fastest way to complete "The Art of Conversation" achievement?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71115/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-complete-the-art-of-conversation-achievement)

Comment: We will have to decide the site policy for duplicates where this is concerned.  Given the way the achievements are structured I don't see a harm in having unique questions for each.  Folks searching the web will find them using the achievement names, and may be interested in only one small section of convos, or the whole she-bang.  If you feel his question "does not show any research effort, is unclear or unhelpful" then downvote - but I would disagree with you.    Speaking from experience in this area, @skovacs1 did a lot of work to put this stuff together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did a run through with a new character, noting when each of the conversations became available. This was compiled by listening to each conversation as soon as they became available. Some of these conversations are only available after having heard previous conversations and the specific dependencies are as of yet undetermined.

Adria stops talking to you after you start *Heart of Sin* in act III and by then any conversations not heard have certainly been missed.

### Act II

- **Adria and Cain**: Available from the time after you complete the quest *Unexpected Allies* and before you accept the quest *Betrayer of the Horadrim* until you begin Act III.
- **The Price of Victory**: Available from the time after you complete the quest *Unexpected Allies* and before you accept the quest *Betrayer of the Horadrim* until you begin Act III.
- **Leah's Birth**: Available from the time after you complete the quest *Unexpected Allies* and before you accept the quest *Betrayer of the Horadrim* until you begin Act III.
- **Motives**: Available from the time after you complete the quest *Unexpected Allies* and before you accept the quest *Betrayer of the Horadrim* until you complete the quest *The Black Soulstone*.
- **Adria's Capture**: Available from the time after you complete the quest *Unexpected Allies* and before you accept the quest *Betrayer of the Horadrim* until you complete the quest *The Black Soulstone*.
- **The Mad Wizard**: Available after accepting the quest *Betrayer of the Horadrim* until you complete the quest *The Black Soulstone*.

  - **Tyrael's Warning**: Available after hearing the conversaton *The Mad Wizard* until you complete the quest *The Black Soulstone*.
- **Your Daughter**: Available from the time after you complete the quest *Betrayer of the Horadrim* and before you accept the quest *Blood and Sand* until you begin Act III.
- **Belial and the Soulstone**: Available from the time after you complete the quest *Betrayer of the Horadrim* and before you accept the quest *Blood and Sand* until you complete the quest *The Black Soulstone*.
- **Magic**: Available from the time after you complete the quest *The Black Soulstone* and before you accept the quest *The Scouring of Caldeum* until you begin Act III.
- **Adria's Quest**: Available from the time after you complete the quest *The Black Soulstone* and before you accept the quest *The Scouring of Caldeum* until you begin Act III.
- **Ensnaring Belial**: Available from the time after you complete the quest *The Black Soulstone* and before you accept the quest *The Scouring of Caldeum* until you begin Act III.

### Act III

- **Azmodan**: Available from the time after you begin act III and before you accept the quest *The Siege of Bastion's Keep* until you accept the quest *Heart of Sin*.
- **Suffering**: Available after accepting the quest *Turning the Tide* until you accept the quest *Machines of War*.
- **The War's End**: Available after accepting the quest *Machines of War* and after hearing the conversation *Suffering* until you accept the quest *Heart of Sin*.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to get The War's End after accepting Machines of War.

Comment: It seems that you need to complete suffering before you can complete "The War's end"

Comment: Thanks @Anders I've yet to run through again with another new character, speaking with nobody and then tracing back dependencies for all the conversations. I just went with first and last availabilities because, for the sake of the conversation achievements, those would be the most pertinent since you'd be trying to get them all. I intend add that information in once I've collected and verified it. I have a few characters that haven't convo'd for the last 2-3 acts so I shouldn't have to run a new char all that far in for this data collection.

Answer (score -3):

- **Adria and Cain (Act II)** - Available after completing Unexpected Allies (Part 7).
- **The Price of Victory (Act II)** - Available after completing Unexpected Allies (Part 7).
- **Leah's Birth (Act II)** - Available after completing Unexpected Allies (Part 7).
- **Motives (Act II)** - Available after completing Unexpected Allies (Part 7).
- **Adria's Capture (Act II)** - Available after completing Unexpected Allies (Part 7).
- **The Mad Wizard (Act II)** - Available after accepting Betrayer of the Horadrim (Part 1).
- **Tyrael's Warning (Act II)** - Available right after listening to The Mad Wizard (Act II).
- **Your Daughter (Act II)** - Available after completing Betrayer of the Horadrim (Part 7).
- **Belial and the Soulstone (Act II)** - Available after completing Betrayer of the Horadrim (Part 7).
- **Magic (Act II)** - Available after completing The Black Soulstone (Part 13).
- **Adria's Quest (Act II)** - Available after completing The Black Soulstone (Part 13).
- **Ensnaring Belial (Act II)** - Available after completing The Black Soulstone (Part 13).
- **Azmodan (Act III)** - Available after accepting The Siege of Bastion's Keep (Part 1).
- **Suffering (Act III)** - Available after accepting Turning the Tide (Part 1).
- **The War's End (Act III)** - Available after accepting Machines of War (Part 1).

Comment: Does this answer add anything above what the already existing answer contains? If it does, I'm not seeing it. Additionally the question also asked for when they become unavailable which your answer does not contain. Could you update your answer to include this information? Moreover, you can actualy get Azmodan before accepting The Siege of Bastion's Keep - use a town portal without talking to Tyrael and then enter The Armory to talk to Adria.

Comment: Yes it does: Before starting X quest is a bit confusing, as others have stated with similar answers of yours.

Comment: *Others* being one person in one comment once - very convincing. Phrasing of the information is something that can be recommended as a comment on the existing answer. If you merely intend to respond to an existing answer, it does not warrant adding a new answer, especially if your answer fails to answer the question and does not add any new information beyond that present in the existing answer. If you can recommend a better phrasing, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I have now rephrased. Is this more along the lines of what you had in mind?

Comment: -1, just because I got confused once (which @skovacs1 explained his choice of phrase, that I agree with as it is more specific), please don't use that as a reason to duplicate answers :(

Comment: @skovacs1 actually no, it doesn't.  You basically just rephrased what my answer already gave. lol.