# Diablo 3 conversation achievement from Merchants "Sales and tales"

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

The achievement says to "Listen to all of the towns merchants conversations."
Where are all these merchants located and are there any criteria to start the conversation (e.g. quests etc)?

Comment: I think it's best if you tell us which ones you are having trouble with finding.

Comment: I was thinking someone could list how to get all of them as a reference.

Comment: Link to all conversation achievements http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72159/how-to-collect-all-diablo-3-conversation-achievements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get credit for each "conversation", you simply have to walk close enough to the NPC to trigger their dialogue.

**Act I**

- Arghus the Collector - On the path behind the inn, near where the
  Mayor's cart was stuck.
- Radek the Fence - on the path behind the inn at the fork between the
  boats and the Weeping Hollows.
- Bron the Barkeep - In the inn near the entrance to Leah's room.
- Tashun the Miner - Near Cain's house and the Healer.

**Act II**

- Tilnan the Collector - In the Bazaar against the northwest wall near
  the bridge.
- Silmak the Fence - In the Hidden Camp in the small northwest alcove,
  near the Healer.
- Sadeir the Innkeeper - In the Bazaar's inn in the north corner.
- Lugo the Miner - In the Bazaar to the right of the inn's entrance.
- Squirt the Peddler - In the Bazaar by the fountain near the bridge.

**Act III**

- Vidar the Collector - Far southern corner.
- Litton the Fence - Far western corner.
- Gorrel the Quartermaster - Far eastern corner.
- Botulph the Miner - Southeastern corner, between Gorrel and Vidar.

(taken straight from [d3db.com](http://d3db.com/achievement/i/sales-and-tales))