# When can I get Leah's conversations for the More Than Stories achievement?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

The achievement says to "Listen to all of Leah's conversations."

Because some of these are missable, I'd like to know when Leah's conversations first become available and if and when they become unavailable.

Comment: Answering your own question within a few seconds after posting it; What are you trying to proof?

Comment: @Sjoerd I'm not trying to proof anything. I didn't answer after posting it, I answered as I posted it (the exact same time). [It is officially okay to answer a question as you ask it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). There's a checkbox beneath the question which says "Answer your own question" - try it. If there is something about the question itself that makes it poor, could you please include details as to how I can improve it? Thank you.

Comment: **Apparently you aren't interested in the answer**, as you've given it yourself already. I can understand that sometimes one answers one's own question, a couple of days after posting it because nobody has answered it and one has found the answer oneself. But I frown upon not giving others the chance to answer the question first. It might be allowed (I didn't flag it because I don't know the exact rules on this point), but that doesn't mean I have to like it.

Comment: @Sjoerd I haven't accepted the answer. I cannot in fact for 2 more days. If someone has a better answer, they can feel free to post it and if it is indeed superior, I will accept theirs in stead. You are free to your opinions, but my actions are not only sanctioned, they are encouraged. The best part of having an answer right away is that by having the answers already here rather than letting a question sit unanswered waiting for someone else, we can generate more traffic for the site right away and this way I can share the results of my hours of research.

Comment: @Sjoerd Please read http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/etiquette-of-immediately-answering-ones-own-question

Comment: Link to all conversation achievements http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72159/how-to-collect-all-diablo-3-conversation-achievements

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did a run through with a new character, noting when each of the conversations became available. There are a few that the exact point in the quest is not 100% because a friend joined and I didn't want to hold them up by running back after every single objective. Once you've heard a conversation, if it was missable, it seems to stay around in stead so until I go through with another character and don't talk to anyone, I can't be certain when exactly they can be missed. *Leah's Childhood* is an example of this - you get this conversation when she's following you during *The Broken Blade*, but since she was following my friend, I couldn't collect this one and later it was not available and as such would be missable however once collected, it was available until the end of the act so in these cases, there would be two points at which they become unavailable.

Leah stops talking to you after you finish *The Breached Keep* in act III and by then any conversations not heard have certainly been missed.

### Act I

- **Tristram**: Available after accepting the quest *The Fallen Star* by starting Act I until you complete the quest *Legacy of Cain*.
- **Adria's Death**: Available after accepting the quest *Legacy of Cain* until you are given the objective *Talk to the Priest* during the quest *The Doom in Wortham*.
- **Life With Cain**: Available from the time after you complete the quest *The Legacy of Cain* and before you accept the quest *A Shattered Crown* until you are given the objective *Talk to the Priest* during the quest *The Doom in Wortham*.
- **Adria**: Available from the time after you complete the quest *The Legacy of Cain* and before you accept the quest *A Shattered Crown* until you are given the objective *Talk to the Priest* during the quest *The Doom in Wortham*.
- **Leah's Childhood**: Available from when you are given the objectives to "Retrieve the Beacons" during the quest *The Broken Blade* until you begin Act II.
- **About the Temple**: Available from when you are given the objective to *Enter the Drowned Temple* during the quest *The Broken Blade* until you begin Act II.
- **Leah's Power**: Available after accepting the quest *Trailing the Coven* until you begin Act II.

### Act II

- **About Zoltun Kulle**: Available after accepting the quest *Betrayer of the Horadrim* until you accept the quest *Blood and Sand*.
- **About Adria**: Available after accepting the quest *Betrayer of the Horadrim* until you accept the quest *Blood and Sand*.
- **Remembering Deckard**: Available after accepting the quest *Betrayer of the Horadrim* until you accept the quest *Blood and Sand*.
- **The Archives**: Available from when you are given the objectives to "Open Shadow Locks" during the quest *The Black Soulstone* until you are given the objective *Enter the Soulstone Chamber through the Terminus* during the quest *The Black Soulstone*.

### Act III

- **Concern**: Available from the time after you begin Act III and before you accept the quest *The Siege of Bastion's Keep* until you complete the quest *The Breached Keep*.
- **Hopes**: Available after accepting the quest *Turning the Tide* until you complete the quest *The Breached Keep*.

  - **Dreams**: Available after hearing the converation *Hopes* until you complete the quest *The Breached Keep*. (Humourously, the male Witch Doctor has the wrong audio here)

### Extras

These don't count towards the achievement, but they are also conversations that can be had with Leah:

- Soulstone Instability: Available from the time after you begin Act III and before you accept the quest *The Siege of Bastion's Keep* until you accept the quest *The Breached Keep*.
- The Black Soulstone: Available during the quest *The Breached Keep*.

Answer (score 1):

- **Tristram (Act I)** - Available after accepting The Fallen Star (Part 7).
- **Adria's Death (Act I)** - Available after accepting The Legacy of Cain (Part 1). She'll be a follower at this point, so right click her portrait to talk to her.
- **Life with Cain (Act I)** - Available after completing The Legacy of Cain (Part 15). Before talking to Cain to accept the next quest talk to her.
- **Adria (Act I)** - Available after completing The Legacy of Cain (Part 15). Before talking to Cain to accept the next quest talk to her.
- **Leah's Childhood (Act I)** - Available while on The Broken Blade (Part 10). Just after you enter the Crypt of the Ancients Leah will say, "This is amazing. It reminds me of being a child and searching for lost artifacts with Uncle Deckard." Once she says that you can right click her portrait to hear this.
- **About the Temple (Act I)** - Available while on The Broken Blade (Part 13). Just after you enter the Drowned Temple Leah will say, "Look at this architecture! This predates the Sin War!" Once she says that you can right click her portrait to hear this.
- **Leah's Power (Act I)** - Available after accepting Trailing the Coven (Part 2).
- **About Zoltun Kulle (Act II)** - Available after accepting Betrayer of the Horadrim (Part 1).
- **About Adria (Act II)** - Available after accepting Betrayer of the Horadrim (Part 1).
- **Remembering Deckard (Act II)** - Available after accepting Betrayer of the Horadrim (Part 1).
- **The Archives (Act II)** - Available after accepting The Black Soulstone (Part 3).
- **Concern (Act III)** - Available after accepting The Siege of Bastion's Keep (Part 1).
- **Hopes (Act III)** - Available after accepting Turning the Tide (Part 1).
- **Dreams (Act III)** - Available right after listening to Hopes (Act III).

Comment: Does this answer add anything above what the already existing answer contains? If it does, I'm not seeing it. Additionally the question also asked for when they become unavailable which your answer does not contain. Could you update your answer to include this information?

Comment: It does, for example "About the Temple" is hard to get, you have to use Leah's portrait to talk to her, which is not obvious at all. Also the speach option is not immidiatly available, I had to say something else first then the option "About the Temple" became available.