# How to find the conversation "Victory" needed for the "Everyone Loves Shen" achievement (added in Patch 1.0.5)?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When can I get Covetous Shen’s conversations for the Everybody Loves Shen achievement?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71722/when-can-i-get-covetous-shens-conversations-for-the-everybody-loves-shen-achiev)

As of patch 1.0.5, [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/71723/15772) is not completely consistent with the list I see in the game.

My in-game achievement list, I was missing the "Memories" dialog from Act 3, I am able to get this conversation when talking to Shen after accepting the "The Siege of Bastion's Keep" quest. But I cannot find an dialog for "Victory", even in Act 4.

How can I find the conversation with Shen called "Victory"? Did I miss something?

Comment: Which act is it part of?

Comment: A process of elimination against the English list should help you figure out which it is, and where it can be found.

Comment: it is part of act 4. I already tried elimination, i am missing "memories" and I have the additional "Sieg"

Comment: Just to double-check, you're missing Memories, which is in Act 3.  But you have an extra one on the Achievement list in Act 4, called Sieg.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes thats right.

Comment: I can't help as far as how to get it, but in the English version there is an Act IV conversation called "Victory" (maybe since patch?)

Comment: For the record, I had Everybody ... before the patch, and still have it with the Victory conversation checked off, so it either predates the patch or was auto checked for those who already had it