# Where do I find the talk "Victory" for the "Everybody Loves Shen" Achievement?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When can I get Covetous Shen’s conversations for the Everybody Loves Shen achievement?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71722/when-can-i-get-covetous-shens-conversations-for-the-everybody-loves-shen-achiev)
>   [How to find the conversation “Victory” needed for the “Everyone Loves Shen” achievement (added in Patch 1.0.5)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89237/how-to-find-the-conversation-victory-needed-for-the-everyone-loves-shen-achi)

It is the last box on the checklist and seems to have been added with patch 1.0.5.
It is supposed to be in Act 4 but I can't find it for the life of me.

Where is it?

Comment: like that you linked a duplicate to a duplicate.... BRAAAVVVOOOO