# When can I get The Stranger/Tyreal conversations for the It's Just Us achievement?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

I just realized the achievement title was a pun on "Justice." The achievement says to "Listen to all of the Tyrael's conversations."

Because Tyrael is always running off and disappearing, making it hard to talk to him, it seems like it would be easy to miss a lot of these, so I'd like to know when Tyrael's conversations first become available and if and when they become unavailable.

Comment: Link to all conversation achievements http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71115/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-complete-the-art-of-conversation-achievement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tyrael/The Stranger will even talk to you after you kill the final boss, but conversations with him are often in small spurts.

### Act I

- **Vanished Memories**: Available during the quest *Sword of the Stranger*.
- **The Sword**: Available from the time after you complete the quest *Sword of the Stranger* and before you accept the quest *The Broken Blade* until you are given the objective *Talk to Alaric in the Drowned Temple* during the quest *The Broken Blade*.
- **The Mysterious Coven**: Available after accepting the quest *The Doom in Wortham* until you are given the objective *Talk to the Priest* during the quest *The Doom in Wortham *.
- **The Lords of Hell**: Available from when you are given the objective *Talk to the Caravan Leader* during the quest *Return to New Tristram* until you begin Act II.

### Act II

- **About Your Fall**: Available after accepting the quest *A Royal Audience* until you begin Act III.
- **About Caldeum**: Available after accepting the quest *A Royal Audience* until you begin Act III.
- **Refugees in Caldeum**: Available after accepting the quest *A Royal Audience* until you begin Act III.
- **Corruption**: Available after accepting the quest *A Royal Audience* until you begin Act III.
- **Destruction of Mount Arreat**: Available after accepting the quest *Unexpected Allies* until you begin Act III.

  - **The Last Twenty Years**: Available after hearing the conversation *Destruction of Mount Arreat* until you begin Act III.
- **Zoltun Kulle's Death**: Available after accepting the quest *Betrayer of the Horadrim* until you begin Act III.
- **The Lord of Lies**: Available from the time after you complete the quest *Betrayer of the Horadrim* and before you accept the quest *Blood and Sand* until you begin Act III.

### Act III

- **A Lost Opportunity**: Available during the quest *The Siege of Bastion's Keep*.

  - **Guilt**: Available fter hearing the conversatio *A Lost Opportunity* until you complete *The Siege of Bastion's Keep*.
- **Kulle's Black Soulstone**: Available after accepting the quest *The Siege of Bastion's Keep* until you are given the objective *Talk to Lieutenant Lavail* during the quest *Heart of Sin*.

  - **The Flawed Stone**: Available after hearing the conversation *Kulle's Black Soulstone* until you are given the objective *Talk to Lieutenant Lavail* during the quest *Heart of Sin*.
- **Human Knowledge**: Available after accepting the quest *The Siege of Bastion's Keep* until you are given the objective *Talk to Lieutenant Lavail* during the quest *Heart of Sin*.
- **The Thrill of Battle**: Available after accepting the quest *Turning the Tide* until you are given the objective *Talk to Lieutenant Lavail* during the quest *Heart of Sin*.
- **Tyrael's Command**: Available after accepting the quest *The Breached Keep* until you are given the objective *Talk to Tyrael* during the quest *Machines of War*.
- **The Battle of the Diamond Gates**: Available after accepting the quest *The Breached Keep* until you are given the objective *Talk to Lieutenant Lavail* during the quest *Heart of Sin*.
- **The Eternal Conflict**: Available after accepting the quest *Machines of War* until you are given the objective *Talk to Lieutenant Lavail* during the quest *Heart of Sin*.

  - **The Creation of The World**: Available after hearing the conversation *The Eternal Conflict* until you are given the objective *Talk to Lieutenant Lavail* during the quest *Heart of Sin*.

### Act IV

- **Heaven's Fall**: Available from when you are given the objective *Enter the Vestibule of Light* during the quest *Fall of the High Heavens* until you are given the objective *Detroy Auriel's Prison in the Library of Fate* during the quest *The Light of Hope*.
- **Adria's Treachery**: Available from when you are given the objective *Enter the Vestibule of Light* during the quest *Fall of the High Heavens* until you are given the objective *Detroy Auriel's Prison in the Library of Fate* during the quest *The Light of Hope*.
- **The Dark Wanderer**: Available from when you are given the objective *Enter the Vestibule of Light* during the quest *Fall of the High Heavens* until you are given the objective *Detroy Auriel's Prison in the Library of Fate* during the quest *The Light of Hope*.
- **The High Heavens**: Available from when you are given the objective *Enter the Crystal Colonnade* during the quest *The Light of Hope* until the end of the game.
- **Leah's Spirit**: Available from when you are given the objective *Enter the Crystal Colonnade* during the quest *The Light of Hope* until the end of the game.
- **Malthael**: Available from when you are given the objective *Enter the Crystal Colonnade* during the quest *The Light of Hope* until the end of the game.

  - **Malthael's Fate**: Available after hearing the conversation *Maltheal* until the end of the game.
- **The Prime Evil**: Available from when you are given the objective *Enter the Crystal Colonnade* during the quest *The Light of Hope* until the end of the game.