# When can I get Kormac's conversations for the For the Order achievement?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

The achievement says to "Listen to all of the Templar's conversations."

Most of his conversations seem to be available up until the end, but there are a few that are missable so I would like to know when Kormac's conversations first become available and if and when they become unavailable.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Thanks. I wasn't sure if it was a 'C' or a 'K' off the top of my head.

Comment: Link to all conversation achievements http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72159/how-to-collect-all-diablo-3-conversation-achievements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As all the followers appear before you after you defeat the final boss, almost all of their conversations are available until the end of the game, but there are a few that can be missed so I'll mark those with a +. Many of the conversations will unlock only after having heard other previous conversations, but will not become available until the point specified. Also, some of the follower conversations may be hidden if they are not following you, but by having them follow you, you can get a complete list (without the extras).

### Act I

- **Becoming a Templar**: Available after accepting the quest *The Fallen Star* by starting Act I until the end of the game.
- **Sins**: Available after accepting the quest *The Broken Blade* until the end of the game.
- **Initiation**: Available after accepting the quest *Trailing the Coven* until the end of the game.
- **Lessons**: Available after accepting the quest *The Imprisoned Angel* until the end of the game.

### Act II

- **Seeking the Truth**: Available from when you are given the objective *Go through the Sundered Canyon* during the quest *Shadows in the Desert* until the end of the game.
- **A Dangerous Journal**: Available after accepting the quest *The Road to Alcarnus* until the end of the game.
- **Confronting Fears**: Available after accepting the quest *A Royal Audience* until the end of the game.
- **The Past Revealed**: Available after accepting the quest *The Black Soulstone* until the end of the game.

### Act III

- **The Torn Page**: Available after accepting the quest *The Siege of Bastion's Keep* until the end of the game.
- **The Templar's Research**: Available after accepting the quest *Turning the Tide* until the end of the game.
- **+ The Truth**: Available after accepting the quest *The Breached Keep* until you complete the quest *The Breached Keep*.
- **Secrets of the Tome**: Available after accepting the quest *Machines of War* until the end of the game.

### Act IV

- **A Templar's Lesson's**: Available after accepting the quest *Fall of the High Heavens* until the end of the game.
- **+ Adria's Betrayal**: Available after accepting the quest *Fall of the High Heavens* until you accept the quest *The Light of Hope*.
- **Shadows of the Coven**: Available after accepting the quest *Fall of the High Heavens* until the end of the game.

### Extras

These don't count toward the achievement

- A Hero's Honor: Available from when you are given the objective *Talk to Auriel and bring your quest to an end* during the quest *Prime Evil* until the end of the game.
- Diablo Vanquished: Available from when you are given the objective *Talk to Auriel and bring your quest to an end* during the quest *Prime Evil* until the end of the game.
- Fallen Comrades: Available from when you are given the objective *Talk to Auriel and bring your quest to an end* during the quest *Prime Evil* until the end of the game.

Comment: Do you know how to get the Act V ones? Especially "Kormac's Unease". It's supposed to be in quest 2. Souls of the dead. But I've done it over and over again with and without the templar as follower, I'm not getting it.

Answer (score 0):

Just as you start act 5, as long as you have Kormac as your follower, it will come up. Do not assist Lorath yet, as you will still get act 4 conversations as well,  for just in case yoummissed any. I am personally still not getting Templar's Lesson

Comment: If you are answering a comment on another answer, you might consider making it stand on its own.  As it is, it is unclear what you mean by "it".  I'm guessing it's Kormac's Unease but that's not clear in your post.