# Cannot get Shen's "God or Man" conversation

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

Having troubles getting the "God or Man" conversation from Covetous Shen, our beloved jeweler. Other post on this site (like ALL other sites of the internet) state the conversation should appear between the start of "Beneath the spire" up to the "Prime evil" quest. [This link](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71115/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-complete-the-art-of-conversation-achievement) says :

> Beneath the Spire - Begin Quest: Talk to Haedrig for 2 conversations and Covetous Shen for 3 conversations.

In game, I do only have two conversations:

[image]

I tried anything... even make the complete act 4 in normal mode and go to town at any quest step (whenever I saw a change in "objectives", I went to the damn jeweler)... but really cannot get this conversation.

I also tried to join a game of a friend having Covetous Shen with the "God or Man" conversation. But for me there was only the two of the linked image.

Please help if you have any idea of what is going on !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting a new character fixed it... don't know why. No patch (it's tomorrow morning) and I could get it with this new char. Could still not get it on both my barb 60 and my DH 60 yesterday...
Kind of weird. But if someone have the same problem, try making a new char (made WD, but dont think it has anything to do with this).

Comment: most likely it was a server side hot fix that was recently performed

Comment: Donno, I tested the day before with my barb. Now after 1.0.4 I tested once more with the barb, and I could get the God or Man conversation (not useful anymore ofc).

Comment: Didn't have to create/start a new char, just use a different char.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: *Sometimes a dialogue option remains hidden until you have opened another one that is available. Also, sometimes they eventually go away later in the game.  I believe I had to have "The Hunt Continues" and "Leah's Soul" discussions before "God or Man" appeared to speak about, but this particular conversation should not disappear if you don't get it immediately.*

As the conversational option 'God or Man?' should be present during the quest 'Beneath the Spire' this would suggest starting at 'The Light of Hope', and then completing this quest, returning to town at the start of Beneath the Spire and attempting the conversation.

[This thread here](http://forums.d2jsp.org/topic.php?t=63091803&f=68) indicates that some people have had issues getting this conversation to appear available. It suggests starting from the quest before and playing it through to the correct point, and then holding the conversation with Shen.

Your screenshot shows the conversational option for 'Ruin and Corruption' - this is only available during 'Beneath the Spire' *after* meeting Imperius for the first time - which is not the start of the quest so I would suspect the above should sort this out for you.

Comment: well... the last point of Light of Hope is "Enter the crystal collonade". When you do so (getting in the portal), you are at the starting point of "Beneath the spire". But... you cannot go back in town until you talk to Imperius (game says "cannot use this skill"). Consequently, there is NO WAY to talk to Shen before talking to Imperius. Also, when you use the "change quest" option to place the current quest to "begin quest" of Beneath the spire and then start new game, you'll see that the "talk to imperius" is immediately completed. Your suggestion sadly does not work...

Comment: btw, you cannot pass the portal back before talking to imperius. You are completely true about "Ruin and Corruption", it appears when talking to Imperius. Had it when going back to town after the cut-scene. But still, I cannot get back in town before talking to Imperius...

Comment: I just created a new game at Normal > Act 4 > Beneath the Spire - I was teleported into Bastions Keep and then I proceeded to speak to Shen. I had to have "The Hunt Continues" and "Leah's Soul" discussions before "God or Man" appeared to speak about.

Comment: This is exactly what I made when I took the screenshot. I dont have "The hunt continues", neither "Leah's soul". Rather, I have "Tell me about yourself" and "Ruin and corruption". This just does not work for me... I also precised in my first post that I joined games with other people having the "God or man" conversation... without any success...

Comment: What is your current status of Shen's achievement?

Comment: Just need this last one...